# POST List<object> API ASP.NET via Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api

My ajax post:

```
var data = [
            {
                "Item": "B0104-0080J01DTT13",
                "Stock": "C022",            
                "Inventory": 0               
            },
            {
                "Item": "B0104-0080J01DTT13",
                "Stock": "C022",            
                "Inventory": 0               
            }];

    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: My URL,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',                 
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

            });
}
```

My ASP API FUNCT:

```
[HttpPost]

public string MyFunction(List<object> DataInput)
{

    return "myreturn";

}
```

When I run: para "DataInput" does have any value, it may be null.
But pass para is object not a List like: (object DataInput), it runs correctly.
Anyone have a idea for my problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

first you should define a class for example

```
    public class myclass{
       public string Item{ get; set; }
       public string Stock{ get; set; }
       public string Inventory{ get; set; }
}
```

so use these class like:

```
    [HttpPost]

public string MyFunction(List<myclass> DataInput)
{

    return "myreturn";

}
```

Comment: It may be needed also to add `[FromBody]`, as follows: `public string MyFunction([FromBody] List<myclass> DataInput)`. Furthermore, it is a widely accepted convention that class names are capitalized: `class MyClass`.

Comment: Yes CamleCase is best choice for class name

Comment: Of course. I already declared class object. But para is only a object: it pass well ( when test: return para, I see values ), and para is a list of objects ( values return is nothing )/.

Answer (score 0):

use this ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: My URL,
                data: {'DataInput':data},
                dataType: 'json',                 
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            });
```